# Android Activity from Notification - FragmentManager backstack is zero

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I searched around but couldn't find an answer. 
My app is based on fragments, and `MainActivity` is the entry point. When the user clicks on a notification, I trigger the desired behaviour with a `PendingIntent` that contains specific flags as to what fragment needs to be invoked.

My problem occurs when the fragment I need is already being displayed. When the `MainActivity` is entered through the `PendingIntent`, the `fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()` will return zero. I guess that this happens because the activity is a different instance than what I already had running. Then the same fragment is invoked again and this messes up my UI (and potentially crash because the `Otto` bus had already been registered).

My question is: what is the best way to detect the state of the running app (i.e. which fragment is being displayed) when the activity is triggered from a notification? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gordak suggestion, I was able to figure out my problem. What I needed was a combination of flags in my (pending)Intent:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This way, if the invoked activity is on top, it won't be destroyed (thus keeping the FragmentManager's backstack) but the method `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` will be triggered, letting you react to it. This is described in the documentation for 
[`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do that with the [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) class.
You have several interesting methods. For example, `findFragmentByTag(String tag)` enables you to know if a Fragment with a particular TAG exists.

Also, are you sure you are not recreating a new Activity (on top of the current one ) ?